# My Google_drive api shows lastModifyingUser as blank string "", when this behaviour will occur?

Tags: google-drive-api

My Google_drive API shows lastModifyingUser as a blank string "", when this behavior will occur?

I have checked even if the file is created the first time, in that scenario `createdBy` name and `modifiedBy.dispalyName` is same.

Comment: Are you trying to get that information via `Files.get`? Have you experienced this behaviour in one file only? Can you show the code you're working on?

Comment: Yes I have checked by hitting drive-api from postman, so it is happening with the file which is shared with me. and it is happening with single file only

Comment: How was this file created?

Comment: It is shared from some other drive. and its mp4 file

Comment: Have you tried getting `lastModifyingUser` of a `Revision`? Are you getting the same behaviour? Also, did you check if there were other abnormally empty fields in the response?